# Euclid's Lemma Clarification

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In class, we learned that if $p$ is a prime, and $p|a_1a_2a_3...a_k$, then $p|a_i$ for some $1\leq i \leq k$.

We also learned that if $p$ is prime, and $p|ab$, then $p|a$ and $p|b$.

I am confused, isn't the second statement essentially just a condition of the first statement where $a_1 = a$ and $a_2 = b$? In this case, shouldn't $p|a$ not necessarily divide $a$ and $b$?

Please explain!

Comment: The two statements are, in fact, equivalent.  You can show, by induction, that the second implies the first and you have already seen that the first implies the second.

Comment: Shouldn't the second statement be if $p$  is prime and $p|ab$, then $p|a$ OR $p|b$?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I read too quickly.  As written, the second statement is obviously false.  $2\,|\,6$ but $2\,\nmid \,3$.  They clearly meant to write that $p\,|,a$ $\textit{or}$ $p\,|\,b$.

Comment: The second statement is wrong.  $2|(3\cdot 4)$ does not imply $2|3$ and $2|4$.  It only implies $2|3$ or $2|4$.

Comment: Is the following statement correct: Suppose gcd(a, bc) =d >1. Then there exists a prime p such that p|a and p|bc.

Comment: @AlirezaFirouzja then $d \mid a$ and $d \mid b c$, any divisor (in particular, a prime one) of $d$ divides both.

Answer (score 2):

The lemma doesn't state that $p$ divides $a$ *and* $b$.  It divides $a$ *or* $b$.

The second statement is a special case of the first.  But it also implies the first by an easy induction.